# Should a HMAC secret key not be hard-coded?

Tags: authentication, jwt, hmac

Because if some bad employee stole it, he could impersonate any users.
And if it should not be hardcoded, where sholud it be putted?
I'm thinking to implement JWT authentication.

Answer (score 0):

HMAC secret key is a plain text. As any private/secret text, you should avoid to store (hard-code) text as simple/plain string, because it can be revealed using disassembling.

So yes, it is a good thing to somehow obfuscate the secret key, doing at least simple text transform. In general you can choose any kind of transformation.

One of the approaches is to use encoding/decoding for transformation: your secret key is stored in source as encoded string, and decoded at runtime when is needed. For example you can use XOR encryption suggested by Google:

```
static String stringTransform(String s, int i) {
   char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
   for(int j = 0; j<chars.length; j++)
      chars[j] = (char)(chars[j] ^ i);
   return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

This function should be used for both encryption and decryption, "i" is an any random value.